# Node.js localhost server cant mentain session with my php localhost

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs, session, xampp

I have my ReactJS website running with "npm start", on "localhost:3000". I have my XAMPP PHP server on "localhost" where I have my api for back-end. I communicate with "fetch" function with my php server and I see a problem - every time I make a request I see that new session is created - I cannot maintain any session info like login, etc..

If I build my app and put it on the XAMPP server - everything is ok, React website works, the session remains, but not between those two localhost, not in my development phase.

Anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong? I dont want to build my website every time I want to check if it works and also I dont want to switch to any other back-end tech.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably a CORS issue: I believe different ports are considered different origins, so your session state (cookies?) wouldn't be shared. Easiest solution might be setting up a [reverse proxy in apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)  to your localhost:3000. That way everything's on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using "Webpack". In order to circumvent this in development mode - you can use the [Proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) feature of Webpack.

> Proxying some URLs can be useful when you have a separate API backend development server and you want to send API requests on the same domain.

The minimal configuration is simply (assuming the backend is on port 80):

```json
"proxy": "http://localhost:80/",
```